# Using python to pipe data to input of a currently running process

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create an app on my django website that should be able to manage a running process. Things i would like the app be able to do are for example starting or stopping the process, sending input and receiving output. Would it be possible to pipe data using python to an already running process so that process can use the data as commands or user input?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which process library are you using (if not subprocess, use subprocess), what does your django code look like for this particular function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to launch the process as a `subprocess` of your Python process, and ensure that Python uses `PIPE` to communicate with it:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["tee", "out"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate("abc")  # This will end up in the process's stdin.
```

Reads [the docs here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).